# Is it safe to abort a CHECK TABLE (mysql) query? (check table TBL_NAME fast)

Tags: mysql, sql

Is it safe to abort a CHECK TABLE (mysql) query? (check table TBL_NAME fast)

Or can this have impact on the data? Corruption? The table has GBs of data and the server crashed so, now its checking, and its taking a long time.

So if the table is in good state, and you run this query, and abort it, can it cause corruption?

Answer (score 5):

`CHECK TABLE` is always safe to abort.